# Load Balancing In gitlab server

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

We have setup a Gitlab CI/ CD platform on a single server with multiple Runners and executors running on a number of machines. This has been working well but doesn’t provides assurance of “high availability” due to single server model. We have been asked to create a HA environment with built in load balancing and auto fail over.

We are trying to find if we can achieve this with two Gitlab CI-CD servers running on two different machines, with a “round robin” load balancer in front of them. Users will hit URL of load balancer which will redirect them to one of the servers. Few initial question we have in mind are

•   How project data and meta data will be shared between two servers?
•   Can repositories and source code be shared? Or do we have to maintain two repositories of same project; one in each Gitlab server?
•   Is failover feature inbuilt in Gitlab CI-CD servers? Will users active on one server be auto redirected to other server.

Has anyone tried it earlier? Or any thoughts how this can be done will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no built-in HA capability for Gitlab (be it CE or EE). There is only Gitlab Geo, which provides a read-only copy of your Gitlab Instance in another location.

If you want to provide HA and LB then you have to consider the following:

Since you can set where data, DB and redis cache are located you can model a HA environment pretty easily.

- Gitlab Instance: Can be fully load-balanced since it is just a web application. Load balancer can provide the fail-over aswell. (HTTP and HTTPS)
- File system: This is where repos are stored. You can use a network share to provide resilience (NFS or DFS)
- Redis and your DBMS of choice: Your usual clustering techniques apply here.